# Cron jobs from DB in Django (via APscheduler)

Tags: django, cron

I have some DB records like

```
class Rules(models.Model):
server = models.ForeignKey(Servers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rule_text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

i.e. some rules, linked with server. Each rule is a crontab string like

```
0 9-17/2 * * 1-5
```

I want to call server_stop(server) and server_start(server) basing on all the rules, I have in DB (and add/edit/delete rules)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mb somebody face the same problem, so I'll show my realization

You need:

```
APScheduler # for all work, 
django-apscheduler #only for store scheduler jobs in Django ORM, in my case in Postgres
```

First of all, you need to make a singleton of scheduler (from APScheduler and django-apscheduler) to ensure, that you have always one scheduler and many jobs in it

```
from pytz import utc
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import register_events


class MetaSingleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(MetaSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class SchedulerHandler(metaclass=MetaSingleton):
    scheduler = None

    def retrieve_scheduler(self):
        if self.scheduler is None:
            self.scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone=utc)
            self.scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), 'djangojobstore')
            self.scheduler.start()
            register_events(self.scheduler)
            self.scheduler.print_jobs(jobstore='djangojobstore')
        return self.scheduler
```

in my `urls.py` I call this method to start scheduler when server is starting:

```
scheduler = SchedulerHandler().retrieve_scheduler()
```

now if I need to add job, I just call `add_job` for existing scheduler:

```
def create_cron_job(cron_string, action, rule_id, job_id=''):
    cron_values_list = cron_string.split(' ')
    if len(cron_values_list) == 5:
        print(cron_string, action, rule_id)
        scheduler = SchedulerHandler().retrieve_scheduler()
        if job_id: #I don't need to update job, so if there is a job created, I just delete it and add a new (but you can use .modify() func)
            delete_cron_job(job_id)
        job = scheduler.add_job(
            server_action_task, #here the func that will be called by scheduler
            trigger='cron',
            jobstore='djangojobstore',
            minute=cron_values_list[0],
            hour=cron_values_list[1],
            day=cron_values_list[2],
            month=cron_values_list[3],
            day_of_week=cron_values_list[4],
            args=[cron_string, action, rule_id] #here the args to pass to server_action_task
        )
        return job.id
    else:
        pass


def delete_cron_job(job_id):
    scheduler = SchedulerHandler().retrieve_scheduler()
    scheduler.remove_job(job_id)
```

And at last I add call of this method somewhere in my project (in APIView or Serializer)

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    rule = Rules.objects.create(**validated_data)
    start_job_id = create_cron_job(rule.start_rule, 'start', rule.id)
    stop_job_id = create_cron_job(rule.stop_rule, 'stop', rule.id)
    rule.start_job_id = start_job_id
    rule.stop_job_id = stop_job_id
    rule.save()
    return rule
```

Mb this not a optimal solution but it works

Note, if you have a `cascade model deletion`, you have to manually delete jobs from scheduler. I did it by adding `pre_delete signal receiver` in my `Rules model`

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver    

class Rules(models.Model):
        server = models.ForeignKey(Servers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        start_rule = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        stop_rule = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        start_job_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        stop_job_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        rule_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='common')  # ENUM common / individual


    @receiver(pre_delete, sender=Rules)
    def delete_rule(instance, **kwargs):
        delete_cron_job(instance.start_job_id)
        delete_cron_job(instance.stop_job_id)
```